# 1 point deducted when I down voted an answer

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

I guess I am missing a point here. So I down voted an answer and now this answer has -3 reputation. Can somebody explain why my point is deducted? This is the [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/140217/cant-a-user-change-his-session-information-to-impersonate-others/140219#140219)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You loose rep for down-voting answers. It is used as a deterrent; it discourages unnecessary down-votes, or down-votes that are in your own self-interest rather than the interest of the community.

Down-voting questions, on the other hand, looses you no rep at all.

You can see this answer [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251612/6331944) about it, and the policy on voting down [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)